# How to get the no of rows updated from hive action in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hiveql

While Inserting data into hive table we can see the number of rows updated in the Logs.
Is it possible to get that values in some variable while using hive actions in oozie.

Comment: I am afraid, No. You can not.

Comment: No. You can't get them.

Comment: *"we can see the number of rows updated in the Logs"* -- not always. If I remember well, the ORC SerDe does not display anything. So there is no consistent behaviour.

Comment: Leaving aside the technical feasibility part, I want to understand why you need the updated rows count?

Comment: if the count is less than previous count i need to set up some alerts. I can always do select count(*) But that will unnecessary uses the computation power.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently **not possible** (as already clarified by many in the comments to the original question). There is an OPEN unresolved ticket (HIVE-8244) for this bug in Apache Jira here - [INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE should return count of rows affected](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8244).